# Date or DateTime Object to Be independent of the Page Culture

Tags: asp.net, datetime, date, culture

Dim strTime as String = FomatDateForSave("28/12/2010")

```
Public Shared Function FormatDateForSave(ByVal strDate As String) As Date

        FormatDateForSave = Date.ParseExact(strDate,'dd/MM/yyyy', System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 

    End Function
```

I am expecting strTime to be "12/28/2010" .... But its getting converted to "28/12/2010" ....

The thing is when the operation is performed by `FormatDateForSave` ... it converts it to "12/28/2010" ...

But when it is returned it is again converted to "12/28/2010"

**I have set the Date for Page.Culture to be "dd/mm/yyyy" and want the value to be "mm/dd/yyyy" to be saved in DB.**

Comment: The problem with my solution was When I was saving it into String It was using toString() which uses current Culture. So it changed the Format of the Date.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the date in the db as its native type, not a string.  When you fetch it you should format it then.

Comment: I am saving the date as date in DB ... I am reading date in British format and want to save it in US format in the DB ...

Comment: A date is a date.  You can't save a date as a format.  That is like saying you are storing an integer in octal format.

Comment: The SQL Server is set in US format ... so whatever date I Enter in it should be converted to US foramt ... and I cant change SQL Server to other format's ....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx  What type of those is your date column.

Comment: Its Date and DateTime both .... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx   ..... So by default our DB is 1  101  USA  mm/dd/yy  ...... So I need to convert to US format everytime I save it to DB .... I know I can save British Format in DB too ... But I would like consistent Date & DateTime values in the Database ....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert your date in sql before insert/update operation?
e.g.

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) will give you date in mm/dd/yyyy format.
```

[Sql Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: We are already using this function at lot of places and replacing the function at every place would be tedious .....